# Same Aggregated message is released multiple time through Spring Integration Aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration Aggregator for grouping the messages. It is working fine when messages arrive aggregator at low rate. But at higher rates, same messages group is coming multiple times to output channel. If any one faced same issue / know resolution for this problem, please provide help on this. Thanks..

Comment: Please, share the configuration, tell us which Spring Integration version you use. And how do you understand that it is really the same message group?

Comment: The Spring Integration version is 2.2.0. In the payload of each message, i keep a message Id, i am checking the same message id of first message in each group and i could see same message Id is coming multiple times.

Comment: The many changes (fixes and improvements) have been done to the aggregator since that version. Would you mind upgrading, at least, to the latest `3.0.6`? I think we really may have some `high load` issue for `2.2.0`...